# Purchasing a new mac

Tags: macbook-pro, processing

Right now I'm currently running PT9 on a 2008 Macbook Santa Rosa with 4GB 2.2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo and am looking into getting one of the new MBP i7 quad cores. I can't decide whether or not to go with the 2.0 or 2.2 GHz. Will it make a big difference in speed? I don't really need the graphics upgrade, and will have 8GB of ram. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

check if there is a bus speed difference between the 2.0 and 2.2 models. this can really make difference.

Comment: The bus speed is the same.

http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-comparison-chart/?compare=all-current-macs

Answer (score 2):

Didnt have time to wade through the comparison but have a look here:
http://www.primatelabs.ca/geekbench/mac-benchmarks/

Comment: Benchmarks are the best way to find out about performance.

Comment: This is a great list of benchmarks. Thanks Tim!


Answer (score 2):

You can install the RAM yourself. It's very easy and can save you over a hundred bucks. The difference between 2.0 and 2.2 is minimal, considering the difference in price. Instead, you could opt for the 2.0 one and do the RAM upgrade yourself.
(check out http://www.ifixit.com/Browse/MacBook_Pro for instructions on how to install the RAM)

Comment: Hell yeah, I definitely plan to upgrade the RAM myself. I'm just waiting for Crucial to carry the RAM I need. 

Comment: Thats the best option. I'm running PT9 on the early 2011 2,0 GHz i7 MBP and i edited backgrounds for a 90 minute documentary with no hiccups.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read, RAM will make a bigger difference than CPU speed, so you probably wouldn't notice much difference with the 2.2 GHz. If you can afford to, why not? Keeps your machine futureproof for longer!

Other people might chime in with their own experience too, but that's what I've read for the most part.

Answer (score 1):

The big difference is between i5 and i7, i7s are far better in so many ways. for music purposes just look for a good CPU, RAM (the faster-greater Mhz the better) and the screen size you are comfortable with...

oh! i almost forgot! usbs, firewires, and connectivity is also a big issue for "music laptops"